# Add a new method in wsdl generated by Axis 1.4

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis

I'm in need to add a new service method and expose it to the consumer side. There is an interface generated which holds all the method declarations of service methods. At the top, it says "This file was auto-generated by Axis 1.4 WSDL2Java emitter".
When I located the .wsdl file, it also had the comment that it has been generated by Axis 1.4. 
Considering that I should not manually edit any file which is generated by an api, how do I add a method?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you extend such a class and provide implementations of those methods and "configure your concrete class" as a service. I'm not sure about Axis but we use metro library and that's how we do it but I guess it should be same as in Axis too.